# What are the various levels in ssh -vvv: debug1, debug2, debug3

Tags: openssh

Is each a different side of the connection or a deeper layer of logging. I am interested because of, for example, this excerpt from a vvv output

```
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Connection reset by nnnn port 22
```

Looking through the output I can't determine which side is saying what.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance! Favour returned: question upvoted!  **;-)**  (I don't know why it attracted a downvote in the first place...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The short answer:

Yes!

#### The long answer:

From [`man ssh`][1]:

> **`-v`**
>
>   Verbose mode.  Causes
>   **`ssh`**
>   to print debugging messages about its
>   progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems.
>   *Multiple **`-v`** options increase
>   the verbosity.*
>   **The maximum is 3.**

- To see what it really does, have a look at the [edits on this question][2] as we asked the OP to go from `-v` to `-vvv` (Debug levels 2 and 3 for `-vv` and `-vvv` respectively)
- For even more information, have a look at [RFC4252, Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-6)
  [1]: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html
  [2]: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/483302/revisions
  "SSH forwarded through modem recently started failing"

Comment: So you're saying that `-v`, `-vv`, `-vvv`, are equivalent to `LogLevel DEBUG1`, `LogLevel DEBUG2`, `LogLevel DEBUG3` in the `~/.ssh/config` file.  Then, what ssh argument should I use that will be equivalent to `LogLevel VERBOSE`?

Comment: Also, as a note, the debug3 output can be a little cryptic.  You may want to look up RFC 4252 section 6 for help with the packet numbers.

Comment: @cowlinator Added to answer: Feel free to do this yourself next time!  You can edit any answer here!  (Due to your rep here, you will go through the review process) As to your `LogLevel VERBOSE` question: maybe post an [additional question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)???  **0:-)**

Answer (score 3):

In ssh I have noticed that:

```
ssh -v
    will tell you what is happening mostly on your end
ssh -vv 
    will tell you low level on both ends
ssh -vvv
    will tell you almost everything from both ends.
```

Hence the conversation :

```
debug1:Some useful information from 1
debug2:Some useful information from 2
debug1:Some useful information from 1
debug3:Some useful information about what is passing between both and more..
```